# NoReverseMatch error argument not found, Django newbie

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Greetings fellow programmers,

So I'm a bit of a newbie at posting questions on here, as well as Django in general, and coding for that matter, so looking for constructive criticism. I'm working on building my first from scratch app, a tinder clone, on Django. I've elected to go with a custom model, which has been kinda a pain creating but I wanted to customize the registration so I went with it. I'm stuck at a certain where I'm not sure what's going on. I've looked at similar posts and tried different solutions but it isn't working. The error I'm getting is,
**Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile/(?P[0-9]+)/$']**

I don't understand why the profile.id isn't being passed when I've put it in my url href tag.

Here is my **roots url.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('dating_app.urls')),


] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is **dating_app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from . import views 


app_name = 'dating_app'
urlpatterns = [
#Home page
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
#List of profiles
    path('profiles/', views.profiles, name='profiles'),
#Individual profiles
    path('profile/<int:profile_id>/', views.profile, name='profile'),


#Login page
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name = 'dating_app/login.html'), name='login'),
    #Logout page
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout'),
    #Registration page 
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),


]
```

Here is **dating_app/views.py**

```
def profile(request, profile_id):
    """show a single profile"""
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    context = {'profile' : profile}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/profile.html', context)


def register(request):
    #Register a new user
    context = {}

    if request.POST:
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            description = form.cleaned_data.get("description")
            photo = form.cleaned_data.get("photo")
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            profile = authenticate(username=username,email=email,description=description, photo=photo, password=raw_password)
            login(request, profile)
            return redirect ('dating_app:home')
        else:
            context['registration_form'] = form
    else: #get request 
        form = RegistrationForm()
        context['registration_form'] = form
    return render(request, 'dating_app/register.html', context)
```

**My href tag in base.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' profile.id %}">My Profile</a>
```

**dating_app/register.html**

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Register</h1>


    <form method="post" action="{% url 'dating_app:register' profile.id %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in registration_form %}
            <p>
                {{field.label_tag}}
                {{field}}

                {% if field.help_text %}
                    <small style="color:grey;">{{field.help_text}}</small>
                {% endif %}

                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p style="color: red;">{{error}}"</p>
                {% endfor %}
            </p>
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>


{% endblock content %}
```

**And if needed, here's my models.py where I created a custom user**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager




class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can understand, you do not have a value named `profile` in context. As your `Profile` model is being used for [**`authentication`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser), so you should be able to get it via `user` attribute in template. But unless you are logged in, it won't work. So try like this:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'dating_app:profile' user.id %}">My Profile</a>
{% else %}
    You are not logged in
{% end %}
```

Also, you need to change the action url from:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'dating_app:register' profile.id %}"
```

To

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'dating_app:register' %}"
```

As `register` url does not take any argument(from your urls `path('register/', views.register, name='register'),`).

Comment: Hey man, that totally worked! Thank you, and thanks for replying so quickly!

Comment: But ok, now I am trying to understand your answer. What do you mean profile is not in context? I have it under the profile view. Do you mean it should be in the register view too?  And what do you mean by my Profile model is being used for authentication? I'm still new to understanding how the custom model works. I do understand there is a base user class, so I guess you're saying to just use that built in function in 'user.id' right? Tho I don't understand why profile.id didn't work.

Comment: `Do you mean it should be in the register view too` yes, better use CONTEXT PROCESSORS for that if you want to have specific context for all views. You are using custom authentication user model. `user.id` will automatically work as this is sent to the templates by django

Comment: I guess what I'm not understanding is why does 'user.id' work but 'profile.id' not work? I set 'profile_id' as a parameter in the profile view. And for my update_profile view, where you can edit the profile, I can use both 'user.id' and 'profile.id' interchangeably. How come I can use both there but with this one, I can only use user.id?